# Finding the shortest path with Neo4jrb

Tags: ruby, neo4j

I'm using [Neo4jrb](https://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4j) version `4.0.0.rc.3` with rails and am having trouble calculating the shortest path between 2 nodes.

I have single type of node `A` and a single type of relationship `R`. I'm able to find the direct relationships using `.rels` but don't know how to traverse the graph (without explicitly using Cypher).

Comment: I'm not familiar with `Neo4jrb`, but shortest paths are generally reconstructed as follows: if `k` is the first node traversed on a shortest path from `i` to `j`, the next node traversed will be the first node traversed on a shortest path from `k` to `j`. I believe all shortest path algorithms produce shortest paths from all nodes to node `j` when only the shortest path from `i` to `j` is needed, which is why shortest paths can be reconstructed in this way.

Comment: @CarySwoveland thanks but I'm familiar with the alrogithms themselves. I just don't know how to traverse using `Neo4jrb`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't have any classes or methods in v3 or v4 that give you access to the algorithms the way 2.3 did. You'd need to do write Cypher using the `shortestPath` function.

```
Neo4j::Session.query.match("(martin:Person),(oliver:Person), p = shortestPath((martin)-[*..15]-(oliver))").where(martin: { name: 'Martin Sheen' }).where(oliver: { name: 'Oliver Stone' }) .return(:p)
```

Comment: How do we iterate through the nodes in the path and get their attributes? Right now I am just getting urls of each node. I want to get access to their properties.